# Is there an in-universe reason in Marvel comics and the MCU that so many ancient gods came to Earth and intervened in human affairs?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

In many Marvel stories, and now increasingly in the MCU, many gods and other figures from ancient human mythologies appear as extraterrestrials or creatures from other dimensions.

Out-of-universe, the mythologies of the various cultures of the world offered rich sources of inspirations to the creators of the various series and storylines.

But is there an in-universe reason why so many powerful beings converged on Earth of all planets, and got involved with humans in one way or another, especially with some many larger and more evolved civilizations in the Galaxy that they could have had more interesting dealings with?

[image]

Comment: Semi-Dupe of [What makes Earth special in the MCU?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/187195/20774)

Comment: Maybe all these gods did mess about with lots of other planets too, we just don’t see those adventures because we prefer comics/movies where humans and earth feature prominently.

Comment: IIRC in comics it's because the Celestials happened to choose Earth for their evolution experiments. The presence of Eternals, Deviants, Inhumans, and Mutants all contributed to other races taking an interest in Earth.

Comment: Does it have it anything to do with it being the Nexus Earth?

Answer (score 4):

It's a little bit of a stretch, but I'm assuming that the gods coming to Earth may have been related to the proliferation of super-powered beings. As to why Earth had so many superheroes, supervillains, etc., Loki had this to say (in [Avengers Vol. 8 #3](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/67756/avengers_2018_3)):

> Tell me, why has this one particular, otherwise unremarkable world
> always been such a hotbed for super-powered madness? Why is the Earth
> so uniquely eccentric within the near-infinite number of planets
> strewn across the heavens? Why indeed? Not because of any grand
> purpose, I can assure you. But because of that bubbling, black puddle
> of Celestial regurgitation and the monstrous things that would come
> slithering out of it. Any guesses as to what those monsters were.
> Hmmm? They were YOU! Yes, you Captain America. You and all your
> mutated, gamma-irradiated, web-slinging ilk. And this is who you have
> to thank. The Progenitor. The origin of the world as you know it. The
> god who died so that you might live.